# Serializing exception using Spring Integration + AWS SQS

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to use Spring Integration with Amazon SQS, but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

If I use an in-memory queue as below, everything works fine:

```
<channel id="businessEvents">
    <queue />
</channel>
```

But when I changed it to use AWS SQS as below:

```
<int-sqs:channel id="businessEvents" 
    region-id="us-east-1"
    queue-name="events-sqs" 
    aws-credentials-provider="awsCredentialsProvider"  />
```

I get the following error:

> org.springframework.integration.MessagingException:
>   org.springframework.integration.MessagingException: No serializer
>   found for class br.com.event.RegisterEvent and no properties
>   discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable
>   SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference
>   chain: org.springframework.integration.aws.["payload"])

Do I need to configure anything else on Spring Integration? Or is it something wrong in my bean class?

Comment: can u pls post the code for the class `br.com.event.RegisterEvent`. Have you implemented `Serializable`?

Comment: Hi @redflar3, the class is a bit long, but yes, it implements Serializable. The curious thing is it fails on a "payload" property. I think "payload" is from Spring Integration itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out. We annotated our events (that went to the queue), with @JsonProperty as below:

```
@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty
private long createdAt;
```

But when we use String Integration AWS, we need to use @JsonProperty from another package.

```
@org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty
private long createdAt;
```

Answer (score 0):

> SerializationConfig.Feature ...

It looks like you are somehow invoking JSON serialization (Jackson) and your class is not Jackson-friendly.

Please show the full stack trace when asking questions like this.